# async factory provider and component injection in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, dependency-injection, async-await, factory

I have a problem with injection a dependency that was created with a asynchronous factory provider.

I have a following configuration:

**app.modules:**

```
   @NgModule({
   declarations: [       
      ...
      ...,
   imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ...
        UsersModule.forRoot(),
        ...
        APP_ROUTERS
    ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**APP_ROUTERS**:

```
const rootRouters = [
   {path: '', redirectTo: 'tests', pathMatch: 'full'},
   {
       path: 'users/login',
       component: SUserLoginComponent,
       resolve: {
          localUsers: UsersLocalResolver
       },
   },

   {
       path: '',
       loadChildren: 'app/test/test.module#TestModule',
       canActivate: [SecurityAuthenticationGuard],
       data: {
          preload: true
       }
   },

];
export const APP_ROUTERS: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouters, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'});
```

**user.modules**:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        SUserLoginComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        SUserLoginComponent
    ]
})
export class UsersModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: UsersModule,
            providers: [

                UsersLocalResolver,
                {
                  provide: UsersLocalDbServices,
                  useFactory: (dbservice: IndexedDBService): Promise<UsersLocalDbServices> => {
                    console.log('Factory UsersLocalDbServices');
                    return new Promise<UsersLocalDbServices>(async (resolve) => {
                        if (dbservice.getVersion() === null) {
                            await dbservice.open(LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME);
                        }
                        const instance = new UsersLocalDbServices(dbservice);
                        const result = await instance.setup();
                        resolve(instance);
                    });
                },
                    deps: [IndexedDBService]
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

The service **(UsersLocalDbServices)**, which uses an asynchronous factory, is injected into the **SUserLoginComponent** component, but it is resolved after the component is instantiated.
How is it done, so that the instance exists at the time of creation of the component?

```
export class SUserLoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private router: Router,
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private db: IndexedDBService,
                private securityServices: SecurityServices,
                private usersLocalDbService: UsersLocalDbServices) {
    }
}
```

The problem is that "usersLocalDbService" is a promise, and not the service instance.

I have solved it by doing the following but the truth is that it is horrible:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    this.usersLocalDbService = await this.usersLocalDbService;
}
```

Is there any way to inject a dependency that is instantiated by an asynchronous factory and that the dependency be resolved before the creation of the component?

Answer (score 1):

There were some efforts towards asynchronous DI, but they were dropped years ago. The short answer is: Asynchronous DI is impossible (using angular's implementation). See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279.

The answer by `Mark Hughes` suggests returning a Promise factory. The article the idea was taken from is about using the `APP_INITIALIZER` token to perform asynchronous actions during bootstrap. It's not a general concept.

Answer (score 0):

The examples of using an async factory I have seen (for example https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/#runtime-configuration) seem to use a function that returns a function that returns a promise, rather than just returning a promise directly.

Applying this to your module would give:

```
export class UsersModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: UsersModule,
            providers: [

                UsersLocalResolver,
                {
                  provide: UsersLocalDbServices,
                  useFactory: (dbservice: IndexedDBService) => {
                    return () => {
                        console.log('Factory UsersLocalDbServices');
                        return new Promise<UsersLocalDbServices>(async (resolve) => {
                            if (dbservice.getVersion() === null) {
                                await dbservice.open(LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME);
                            }
                            const instance = new UsersLocalDbServices(dbservice);
                            const result = await instance.setup();
                            resolve(instance);
                        });
                    }
                },
                    deps: [IndexedDBService]
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mark. This solution solves the issue of the component, but if I inject the service into a resolver or another service, the dependency is not the instance (it is not resolved).  This is the output of print in resolver constructor.  " ƒ () {
                            console.log('Factory UsersLocalDbServices');
                            return new Promise(function (resolve) { return __awaiter(_this, void 0, void 0, function () {… "

Comment: @CristianRinaldi do you have an example service showing that problem?

Comment: Yes, I do a "poc" and I upload it so you can see it

Comment: Hmm - I'm wondering if it is because you have registered TestResolver as a provider rather than as a declaration on the module...

Comment: mmm, I think not. I updated the "poc", if you run it you will see the sequence of the initialization and it shows how the dependencies are being injected. (In console)

Comment: @CristianRinaldi i´ve encountered the same problem, given
`{ provide: OAuthModuleConfig,
         useFactory: (service: ConfigService) => {
             service.loadConfig().then(
              (res) => {
                return res as OAuthModuleConfig;
              }
            );
        },
          deps: [ConfigService]
        }`
You end up with a ZoneAwarePromise obj and your actual object in '__zone_symbol__value', so basically useless... 
It´s the actual promise thats returned, ´canñt see how to return the Promise resolved value.